# Why does put(K key, V value) and put(K key, Set<V> value) has a name clash?

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement my own multimap, a wrapper for key to value set map.

Here's the SSCCE

```
public class TreeMapTreeSet<K, V> extends TreeMap<K, Set<V>> {

    public void put(K key, V value) {

    }
}
```

---

It gave me this error:

> Name clash: The method put(K, V) of type TreeMapTreeSet has the same erasure as put(K, V) of type TreeMap but does not override it

AFAIK, wouldn't the erasure be put(Object, Set) which is different from put(Object, Object)?

---

I can only override it if I change it to the following

```
@Override
public Set<V> put(K key, Set<V> value) {
    return value;       
}
```

---

I cannot override it, and cannot not override it as well.
Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The erasure of the inherited method is still `put(Object, Object)`. To see this, consider what you'd get if you assigned it to a raw `TreeMap` variable:

```
TreeMap foo = new TreeMapTreeSet<Integer, Integer>();
```

`foo.put` cannot have signature `put(Object, Set)` here. It must be `put(Object, Object)`.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this problem (without using a different method name)?

Comment: @user607455: Well, you could wrap a `TreeMap` instead of extending it.